# GKE : Ingress to Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, api-gateway, gke-networking

I am migrating from ingress to gateway on GKE and wondering if there are things I could keep from the old configuration or if I have to start from zero with GW.
Also, I use envoy proxy, do I need a specific one per route?

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is related to the GKE Gateway controller. I recommend checking this [Comparison of Ingress and Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gateway-api#comparison_of_ingress_and_gateway). This explains how Gateway is an evolution of Ingress and it will also show you the differences in configuration of Ingress over Gateway.

For additional information,I also recommend checking this document about [Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gateway-api) and [Deploying Gateways](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways). For other concern, you may contact `gke-gateway-feedback@google.com` since this feature is still in the Preview launch stage.